# How to disable 'new item row' area in Devexpress grid

Tags: vb.net, gridview, devexpress

I have a gridview in Devexpress.  At the top of the grid, I have a blank
area that allows me to add a new client to the grid.  The problem is that
when I click on the blank area near the right column, it's as if I had
clicked on the 'Supprimer' button.  I would like to disable that right area so that when I click on it, nothing happens. So this means, I could only add a new client if I click on the left side of the blank area.

I've tried to play around with the ShowingEditor but could not get it to work:

```
Private Sub gvException_ShowingEditor(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles gvException.ShowingEditor

        If gvException.IsNewItemRow(gvException.FocusedRowHandle) Then
            gvException.Columns("Supprimer").OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = True
            buttonDeleteException.Buttons(0).Caption = "Supprimer"
            'e.Cancel = True
        Else
            gvException.Columns("Supprimer").OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = False
            e.Cancel = False
        End If
    End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Really, the way you ask your question... First where it says 'supprimer', its not a button. It looks like a column header. Second, when you press it, your code probably adds a new client. We don't know that! So what are you talking about? Third, unless you have creaded a custom control, there is no such thing as a 'gridview', it looks like a datagridview. These are important details if you ask others to unravel your spaghetti. But I think you need to catch the mouse click event of the datagridview. And do something to prevent the second column header from getting clicked

Comment: First, There are 10 'Supprimer' buttons on the picture (the arrow is pointing at the area above the first 'Supprimer' button, not the header).
Second, yes, there is code to add a new client, it runs when you click on the blank area above the first 'Supprimer' button.  
Thrid,  it's a Gridview from Devexpress (not a DataGridView), as mentionned in the title of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
Private Sub gvException_ShowingEditor(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles gvException.ShowingEditor
    If gvException.IsNewItemRow(gvException.FocusedRowHandle) and gvException.FocusedColumn.FieldName = "Supprimer" Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Abdellah, this worked but the following is more what I was looking for:  `Private Sub GridView1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
            Dim view As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)
            Dim hitinfo = view.CalcHitInfo(e.Location)
            If hitinfo.InRowCell AndAlso hitinfo.RowHandle = GridControl.NewItemRowHandle AndAlso hitinfo.Column.FieldName = "Info" Then
                DXMouseEventArgs.GetMouseArgs(e).Handled = True
            End If
      End Sub `

Comment: Yes good, but this code works well for the Click, but it does not disables the clik event for the 'Supprimer' button if you pass among fields of the new row with the keyboard (tab key). you must use the codes of events `ShowingEditor` and `MouseDown`

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean.  You mean when I move from the 'client' field to the 'Supprimer' field using the 'tab' key.  I'm not handling the 'enter'  or the 'space' key so the click will never be fired.

Comment: Yes exactly what I mean, ok good if you do not handlling the button Keys.